# How to translate slick update to SQL update & slick update a record takes more than 200ms

Tags: scala, slick

This is my slick code:

```
val map = Query(Messages)
                .filter(_.msg_id === msg_id)
                .map(ab => ab.completed_at ~ ab.status ~ ab.total_count ~ ab.accept_count ~ ab.fail_count ~ ab.status_list)
              map.update((Option(completed_at), Option(status), Option(sendcount), Option(acceptcount), Option(failcount), Option(task_id + ":" + "%s".format(status))))
```

I found this update takes more than 200ms and it is quite abnormal, 
Is there anything wrong with the update code? 
Could someone translate the slick update code to real SQL so I can check the efficiency～

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get the SQL statement of your query using the following:

```
map.updateStatement
```

About the time for querying, are you not using a connection pool? If that's the case you could see longer delays when running a query due to the fact that slick is establishing the connection on every db.withSession statement. If you use a connection pool instead it will connect on the first statement and then reuse connections for the next ones (drastically reducing the time for each query).

Have a look at c3p0 if you want to try this, it's compatible with slick, just define your database as follows:

```
val db = {
    val ds = new ComboPooledDataSource
    ds.setDriverClass(...)
    ds.setJdbcUrl(...)
    ds.setMinPoolSize(...)
    ds.setAcquireIncrement(...)
    ds.setMaxPoolSize(...)
    ds.setUser(...)
    ds.setPassword(...)
    Database.forDataSource(ds)
}
```

Have a look at c3p0 docs for details about the various settings you can tweak to get better performances.